# How to stick header table with table-responsive (not javascript)?

Tags: css, angular

I've tried to render a responsive table bootstrap. But header not stick when scroll.
How to stick header table with table-responsive?

[this my code:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-41zdjk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
Thanks you.

Comment: I can't see your header code in the link you provided

Comment: Please put the relevant portion of your code in the question itself. The link to stackblitz is fine, but people should be able to see the code here that is relevant to the question. See [ask] and [mre].

Comment: You can use position:sticky; example : `thead tr th {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  background:white;
  box-shadow:0 1px;
}`